# Do I need prepared statement on each query?

Tags: php, pdo

```
$query = "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = :username";
$query_params = array(':username' => $_POST['username']);
try
{
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}

$row = $stmt->fetch();
if($row)
{
die("This username is already in use");
}
```

This all works, but:

1. Do I really need prepared statement if the query is just `SELECT` or `SELECT COUNT` ?
   Because, if there is no `INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE` operations on the table - I suppose there is no dangerous of sql injection or spam ?
2. Do I really need `try/catch` statement each time I go to database ?

Comment: There is *always* the danger of SQL injection when working with external values. What kind of statement it is doesn't matter. The point of SQL injection is making it a *different* statement

Comment: Use prepared statements at *any* point that a user could be providing data to the query for. This is rule number one when accepting any user data. Just because they're not altering data with an update/etc. it doesn't mean they can't read private information and use it to their advantage.

Comment: You don't need to use PDO **unless** there are variables inside the SQL statement which your users *might* be able to alter. Which you are doing. [Remember little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: [http://xkcd.com/327/](http://xkcd.com/327/) Imagine if someone managed to make your `$_POST['username']` variable `Robert'); DROP TABLE users ;--` If you didn't sanitize your data then you'd be up a creek I'm not sure I'm allowed to mention on a public site ;)

Comment: SQL Injection is not just about `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` vars. Also consider Second Order SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as connection to database goes this is the only approach you need. Try and Catch: (if you are using MySql database )

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME', 'USER', 'PASS', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Plus, there is a built-in count query for count:

`$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();`

Here is a good tutorial, if you never knew

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: Thanks to everyOne. Enough for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

If there are any variables that you put in the query that the user can alter in any way, you should(must) use prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

There is always a danger of SQL injection even on SELECT statements because someone could terminate the SELECT and append an INSERT statement in the username. However, if you are using mysql_real_escape_string() or else your DB classes escape your values for you then you don't have to worry about try/catch on a SELECT statement. If you have escaped your values this is sufficient for your SQL:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username); // escape the string first.
$query = "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
```

Answer (score 2):

1) No, you don't have to use prepared statements; you could use e.g. PDO::query and PDO::quote to build up a query using string concatenation. HOWEVER -- YES, any time you're using externally-supplied strings, there is a risk of damage from SQL injection, even if you're just doing a SELECT. For example, an attacker could try to run two statements in one by using a ";" in the supplied string. The PDO::quote is another way to safeguard against this.

2) You could throw the error out of your calling code, but somewhere you'll have to consider error handling.